# rename an array key recursively

Tags: php, arrays

I have been trying to solve this on my own but can't find a solution that I can understand.

I have this array that is created on the fly when my application loads by reading dynamic config files.

My problem is that I would like to have an array called `alias` that would be picked up and rename the parent array that `['@attr']` is under. Here is an example to show what i mean.

```
[database] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array // Would be renamed to "production"
                (
                    [host] => test
                    [user] => test
                    [pass] => test
                    [name] => test
                    [port] => test
                    [@attr] => Array
                        (
                            [alias] => production
                            [name] => live
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array // Would be renamed to "development"
                (
                    [user_data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array // Would be renamed to "three"
                                (
                                    [user] => sample
                                    [@attr] => Array
                                        (
                                            [alias] => three
                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => Array // Would be renamed to "two"
                                (
                                    [user] => sample
                                    [@attr] => Array
                                        (
                                            [alias] => two
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [host] => test
                    [user] => test
                    [pass] => test
                    [name] => test
                    [port] => test
                    [@attr] => Array
                        (
                            [alias] => development
                        )

                )

        )
```

This is my code so far

```
private function _applyXmlAlias($array)
        {
            foreach ($array as $config)
            {
                if (is_array($config))
                {
                    if (isset($config['@attr']['alias']))
                    {
                        $alias = $config['@attr']['alias'];

                        unset($config['@attr']['alias']);

                        if (empty($config['@attr']))
                        {
                            unset($config['@attr']);
                        }

                        $this->_alias[$alias] = $config;

                        break;

                        //$this->_temp = reset();


                    } else {

                        $this->_applyXmlAlias($config);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

If I do a print_r of my `_alias` property I get this

```
   Array
(
    [production] => Array
        (
            [host] => test
            [user] => test
            [pass] => test
            [name] => test
            [port] => 3306
            [@attr] => Array
                (
                    [name] => live
                )

        )

    [development] => Array
        (
            [user_data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [user] => sample
                            [@attr] => Array
                                (
                                    [alias] => three
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [user] => sample
                            [@attr] => Array
                                (
                                    [alias] => two
                                )

                        )

                )

            [host] => test
            [user] => test
            [pass] => test
            [name] => test
            [port] => 3306
        )

)
```

Note: I'm not sure why my loop only captures the last nested array with the key `alias` and not the other keys that have the values `production` and `development`

Any ideas on how I can approach this? I feel that I am close just need a little guide in the right path.

thanks

EDIT: Updated my function to reflect current attemps

Comment: Needs more than a break... see my comments below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm is doing a depth-first search. The problem is that it doesn't know when to terminate.

Instead of a void return-type, try something like this:

```
    private function _applyXmlAlias($array)
    {
        $found_alias = FALSE;
        foreach ($array as $config)
        {
            if (is_array($config))
            {
                if (isset($config['@attr']['alias']))
                {
                    $this->_alias = reset(array_values($config));
                    $found_alias = TRUE;
                       break;
                } else {
                    if ($this->_applyXmlAlias($config)) {
                       $found_alias = TRUE;
                       break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $found_alias;
    }
```

Comment: what would you recommend? should I throw a `break` in there? If I have tried a similar approach but end up only getting a value from one of the keys. I have update my code to show my latest attempt

Comment: Updated with a sample... breaks won't solve it completely, you need a way to tell the caller (it's depth-first) that you've found something and it should break, too.

Answer (score 0):

Quite possibly not the most elegant solution, but works.

```
function renameArr($arr) {
    foreach($arr as $key=>$val) {
        if(is_array($val)) {
            if(isset($val['@attr']['alias'])) {
                unset($arr[$key]);
                $key = $val['@attr']['alias'];
            }
            $arr[$key] = renameArr($val);
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}
```